# How do you cast supernova?

Tags: magicka-square-tablet

One of the achievements says "Cast supernova". I tried many things but nothing works. How do you cast a supernova?

Comment: man are you still alive?

Answer (score 4):

You can cast Supernova by combining Lightning, Shield, Life, and Fire.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a SuperNova by casting the following combo:

( Steam - Steam - Lightning - Lightning - Arcane ) + AOE Cast

With the default PC keyboard layout, that transfers to these keys:

( <kbd>F</kbd> - <kbd>Q</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> - <kbd>Q</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd> ) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> and hold.

Comment: Well the problem is its a  app not the computer game

Comment: Oh! ok. It was not apparent from the question. You should probably add the 'ios' tag to the question so that other users are not misled like myself.